# Running JUnit tests in Gradle under Java 1.5 produce different results under 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, gradle

I have a unit test on some code running under Java 1.5. 
In Eclipse I run the test and it returns the following string with the `Exception.getMessage()`:

> The Test has Failed: java.lang.String

but running it with Gradle with targetCompatibility set to 1.5 returns

> The Test has failed: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

I am guessing the gradle junit runs under the 1.7 that gradle is running under. There doesn't seem to be a way to change this.

Is there a way to make a unit test return the same string (without hacking the code) under Java 1.7 and Java 1.5 and is there any documentation that will show why this is different now?

Comment: Well, why don't you run gradle with the 1.5 JDK? Also, what is the test?

Comment: Gradle will not run on anything under 1.6, and the unit test is a unit test to confirm a Class Cast Exception is thrown, we are using assertThat(exception.getMessage(),isEqual("The Test has failed: java.lang.String"));

Comment: Instead of checking the exception message, check that exception type is `ClassCastException`. If necessary, you can additionally check that the message *contains* `java.lang.String`.